A curious Diophantine problem
Let $a, b, c, d$ be positive integers where $\gcd(a, b)=\gcd(c, d)=\gcd(b, d)=\gcd(bd, ad+bc)=1$ and $\min(b, d)>1$. Is it possible to have
$$bd(ad+bc)^{2}\varphi(a)\varphi(c)=ac\varphi(bd)\varphi^{2}(ad+bc)$$
where $\varphi$ denotes the Euler totient function?

Can I ask what makes it curious for you?

Do you have some reason to believe this equality sometimes holds? or, never holds, Q_p?

It is possible.
Write $f(n) = \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = \prod_{p \mid n} \frac{p-1}{p}$ and let $b,d>1$ such that $(b,d)=1$. Then let $k=b^2+d^2$, $a=kd$ and $c=kb$. It follows that $(a,b)=1$, $(c,d)=1$ and $(bd, ad+bc)=1$. Furthermore
$$\begin{split}f(a)f(c) &= f(k)^2f(a/k)f(c/k) \\
&= f(k^2)^2f(d)f(b) \\
&= f(bd)f(ad+bc)^2\text{.}\end{split}$$
For example $a=13 \cdot 2, b=3, c=13 \cdot 3, d=2$ works.

I think you want $k=b^2+d^2$ but otherwise looks good

@vuur, thanks for this elegant answer! Can you please shed more light on how you found the solutions, and whether your method produces all solutions?

First I rewrote the equation in terms of $f$ because then one can see that the equation is independent of exponents in the prime factorizations and easier to reason about. Next I tried $p$-adic orders of some primes ($2$, $3$, the largest one dividing $ad+bc$), but that didn't lead to anything.  Finally I made the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $c$ explicit in the LHS and saw how to match up terms on both sides of the equation. I do not know if these are all solutions.

In fact, now, on reflection, it is probably possible to take $k=(b^2+d^2)^e$ for any positive $e$. Are those then all solutions? I don't know.
